# Compare and Grep using shell script

Tags: shell

I have two files A and B.

A looks like

```
2024007 current events rules
2024008 current events rules
2024009 current events rules
2024010 current events rules
2024011 current events rules
2024012 current events rules
2024013 current events rules
2024014 current events rules
2024015 current events rules
2024016 current events rules
2024017 current events rules
2520160 tor rules
2520161 tor rules
2520162 tor rules
```

and file B also has

```
1326 ActiveX Attack Rules
1327 Attack Response Rules
1328 BOTCC Portgrouped Rules
1329 BOTCC Rules
1330 CHAT Rules
1331 CIARMY Rules
1332 Compromised IP Rules
1333 Current Event Rules
1334 Deleted Rules
1335 DNS Attack Rules
1336 DOS Attack Rules
1337 DROP Rules
1338 Dshield Rules
1339 Exploit Rules
1340 FTP Attack Rules
1341 GAMES Rules
1342 ICMP INFO Attack Rules
1343 ICMP Attack Rules
1344 IMAP Attack Rules
1345 Inappropriate Website Access Rules
1346 INFO Rules
1347 Malware Rules
1348 Miscellaneous Rules
```

I need to search Rule categories(current events rules etc.) from File B -> A,and if it matches take the Id Stored in File B next to Rule Category(like 1326-48). and update in database with the ID present in File A.

Comment: Looks like it's time to write some code!

Comment: the above data is in columns separated format ...

Comment: There are not common fields between those two files.

Answer (score 0):

On my point of view there is not enough details to help you as I would like to, but from what I understand, you should have a look at `perl` scripts

With perl you'll be able to parse your file easily and do what you want with your datas ...

Hope it helps.